# How to prove (x+y)/z + (y+z)/x + (x+z)/y>=6 when x,y,z>0

Tags: proof

This question actually had two parts. In the first part I had to prove that `a + 1/a >=2`. I proved it by rearranging it to `(a-1)^2 >= 0`, which is always true.

So, I thought the second problem would require a similar method.

```
(x+y)/z + (y+z)/x + (x+z)/y >=6, where x,y,z>0
```

But I cant figure it out.
I've tried simplifying it and factoring it for ideas but I've got nothing.

Comment: Maybe try [math.se].

Comment: @Welbog The title specifies x,y,z > 0

Comment: Ah, titles. The last place one looks for detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not programming question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know that `a + 1/a >= 2`, the second part is easy. Define:

```
a := x/z,  b := y/z,  c := y/x
```

and now

```
(x+y)/z + (y+z)/x + (x+z)/y = x/z + y/z + y/x + z/x + x/y + z/y
                            = a + b + c + 1/a + 1/c + 1/b
                           >= 2 + 2 + 2
                            = 6
```